# Close button in wrong position

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a dialog box where I have a X as a close button. I have some snippets from my code shown below. For some reason, it is pushing down the title text leaving space above it. But I want it to be level, without all that wasted space.

Where am I going wrong?

[image: Too much white space]

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
  paper: {
    padding: theme.spacing(2),
    textAlign: 'left',
    color: theme.palette.text.secondary,
    height: '100%',
  },

  dialog: {
    position: 'absolute',
    // left: 10,
    top: 50,
  },
  closeButton: {
    position: 'relative',
    right: theme.spacing(1),
    top: theme.spacing(1),
    color: theme.palette.grey[500],
  },
  customizedButton: {
    position: 'relative',
    left: '60',
    top: '60',
    color: 'silver',
  },
}));
```

```
                <Dialog
                  id="myDialog"
                  classes={{ paper: classes.dialog }}
                  //Modal dialog for advice on position
                  onClose={handleCloseTagInstructions}
                  open={openTagInstructions}
                  // onClose={handleCloseImportPGN}
                  aria-labelledby="form-dialog-title"
                  fullWidth={true}
                  // maxWidth={'md'}
                >
                  <DialogActions>
                     <IconButton
                      className={classes.customizedButton}
                      onClick={handleCloseTagInstructions}
                    >
                      <CloseIcon />
                    </IconButton>
                  </DialogActions>
                  <TagContent tagText={currentTag} tagColour={tagColour} />
                </Dialog>
```

Comment: It will need to be `position: absolute` to not have elements effect one anothers' flow. You could also possibly use `display: inline`, but that my still have unwanted impacts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched to absolute and all was good.

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
  paper: {
    padding: theme.spacing(2),
    textAlign: 'left',
    color: theme.palette.text.secondary,
    height: '100%',
  },
  dialog: {
    position: 'absolute',
    // left: 10,
    top: 50,
  },
  closeButton: {
    position: 'absolute',
    right: theme.spacing(1),
    top: theme.spacing(1),
    color: theme.palette.grey[500],
  },
  customizedButton: {
    position: 'absolute',
    left: '60',
    top: '20px',
    color: 'silver',
  },
}));
```

Notice that I added the pixels using 20px.